# ASP.NET MVC TFS Branching

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, branching-and-merging, tfvc

I've read several posts about branch and merge feature of SVC and creating branches in TFS, following those steps I've created branch for a breaking change in a feature of ASP.NET MVC application, 
After successful creation of branch, branched files (new files) excluded from application, attempting to include files in project will create duplicate signature errors.
so I've to carryout changes in original files (files available before branching) now I don't know actual purpose of branches.

If I need to work with existing files why do I need to create branch?

How to setup and configure branching operation in TFS Version Control?

How really it helps?

**Edit:**

[Attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tk0DB.jpg)
I've created a branch @ controller folder (Source Control Explorer), After successful creation of Branch I found two directory in One Controller another Controller-Branch (which is excluded from project by default). Now in what set of files I need to work?

When I Work in "Controllers" file set, these changes push back to other developers and so I don't see any isolation of environment there.

If I need to work in "Controllers-branch" why it is excluded from project? when I attempt to Include "Controllers-branch" to project, code definitions, class names duplicated (i.e., these definitions conflicts with contents of  "Controllers" folder)

Comment: Do you mean creating branches by TFS on web or use VS source control explorer? It can't create TFVC branch on TFS directly. And can you show the links which you were following to? Besides this article shows the way and purpose for TFVC branch https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/branch-folders-files.

Comment: How do you create the branch? Usually, the branch will not cause errors.

Comment: Try to compare them after creating a new branch.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT I have already get through that link and follow same instructions to create a branch; in the way I infer Branch is a Copied version of Source Code file. Is this statement Right?

Comment: @ashok19r91d Yes, after following the doc to create a branch, you need to select the option add file to source control. There are two ways you can add a new created file to source control: **1.** when create a new solution/project, select Add to source control. **2.** If you has already created a file, in VS -> source control explorer -> select the tfvc repo -> right click -> add new items to folder -> select the file you just created -> check in. More details, you can refer https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/add-files-server.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT add branched files to Project will create duplicate signature errors i.e., class(es) method(s) with same name, within same namespace already exists in original files.

Comment: Can you add detail steps to create a branch and add branch files with the error with screen shot if necessary in your question?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT question updated.

Comment: I give the answer for why there has two branches and why Controllers-branch is excluded from your project, and you should convert Controllers to folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why there have two branches `Controllers` and `Controllers-branch`:

It’s because when you created a branch (branching and merging -> branch) based on `Controllers` folder, you also select **Immediately convert source folder to branch (enables visualizations)**, this will convert `Controllers` folder to branch.

[image]

So based on your need, you should convert `Controllers` branch into folder (right click Controllers branch -> branching and merging -> convert to folder).

> Why Controllers-branch is isolate from your project:

It’s because `Controllers-branch` is a branch, and the TFVC branch can achieve these goals:

> •  Manage concurrent work by multiple teams on the same codebase
>
> • Isolate risks that are introduced by different sets of changes to
>   the codebase
>
> • Take snapshots and then support subsequent isolated
>   changes (for example, to create a release branch)

So it should be works isolated. If your work own is not only updated files in `Controllers` folder, but also need to modify files for the whole project, you should create a branch from `ApplicationMain` folder a,d make sure Immediately convert source folder to branch (enables visualizations) is not selected. Then you can work on `ApplicationMain-branch` concurrently from other developers.

[image]

Comment: so after converting **Controllers** branch to folder, I can start working on files in **Controllers** folders, and those changes will be isolated from other team members work right? but I don't believe so because during check in these files will get versioned in server and delivered to other members who PULL (Recursive GET) changesets from server; and I don't see any isolation here.

Comment: No, after converting `Controllers` branch to folder, it's still apart of the project, you should work on `Controllers-branch`, it's isolate from other members.

Comment: but that files are excluded from Project, so no Intelisense helps on writing code; even I don't able to test code by executing application.

Comment: So you should create a branch from the parent folder `ApplicationMain`, and then working on `ApplicationMain-branch`, then you can writing code and test your code concurrently.

Comment: Virtually speaking I need to duplicate my project (in name of Branch), after completing fixes and test cases I can merge back to original folder. and moreover creating `ApplicationMain-Branch` is also equivalent to `Controllers-Branch` i.e., that files too excluded from project, where the same case follows.

My fundamental problem is very simple! I don't able to figure out **where to branch** _(even after knowing How to branch, How branch works)_.

Comment: Yes, since `Controllers-branch` can't meet your requiremnts, you shloud 
 deleted this branch. Then create `ApplicationMain-branch` based on `ApplicationMain` folder. After your work is finished, merge `ApplicationMain-branch` into the main code, and then delete `ApplicationMain-branch`.